# Question on coefficients of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $$P_0(x)=x^3+313x^2-77x-8$$

For integers $n\ge1$, define $$P_n(x)=P_{n-1}(x-n)$$.

Then what is the coefficient of $x$ in $P_{20}(x)$ ?

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. Could somebody help?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Don't close this question, no teacher would assign this

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy: This post lacks source and motivation entirely.   Being homework is a sufficient reason to vote to close a question, but not a necessary one.

Comment: @CarlMummert Well, professor, it includes that he/ they are stuck. If source and motivation need to explicitly be displayed for every post, then why aren't they made into a field such that you can't post a question unless you fill this field? And every question has face value to a segment of users on MSE, perhaps there are some independent studiers who haven't even studied calculus yet, in this instance. In general, I have little indication that the virtue of just answering the question, or leaving off so someone else can benefit from it is observed by 3000 rep members of MSE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$P_n(x)=P_{n-1}(x-n)$$

$$ P_{20}(x)=P_{19}(x-20)$$

$$ = P_{18}(x-20-19)=P_{17}(x-20-19-18)$$

$$ = ...=P_{0}(x-210)$$

$$   P_{20} (x)=(x-210)^3+313(x-210)^2-77(x-210)-8 $$

The coefficient of  x in the above expression is its derivative $$ 3(x-210)^2+626(x-210)-77 $$      at $x=0$, which is $763$

Answer (score 6):

$P_{20} (x)=\left(x-\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{r=20} r \right)^3+313\left(x-\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{r=20} r \right)^2 -77\left(x-\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{r=20} r \right)-8$

$P_{20} (x)=(x-210)^3+313(x-210)^2-77(x-210)-8$

coff . of x=

$ 3\cdot(210)^2+313\cdot(-420)-77=763$

Comment: Observe that coeff. of $x$ is $P_{20}'(0)$. We have $P_{20}'(x)=3(x-210)^2+313\cdot 2(x-210)-77$ which gives us precisly what is written above.

Comment: Yours is the best answer as it used the binomial theorem and no calculus since the tags were algebra and precalculus

Comment: @ AmateurMathGuy: thank you so much bro..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can easily find a formula for $P_n(x)$
$$P_n(x)=P_0\biggl(x-\frac{n(n+1)}2\biggr).$$
Next, use *Taylor's formula* for polynomials. As $P_0$ has degree $3$,
$$P_0(x-a)=P_0(a)+P'_0(a)(x-a)+\frac{P''(a)}2(x-a)^2+\frac{P'''(a)}6(x-a)^3.$$
Thus we obtain the coefficient of $x$ is
$$P'_0(a)-aP''(a)+a^2\frac{P'''(a)}2.$$